# "I'll go with the candidate I'm used to" or "I'll go with the candidate to whom I am used?"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, expressions, idioms, sentence-ends

> I'll go with the candidate I'm used to.

I get that this is colloquial, but, c'mon. Ending a sentence with a preposition?

However, is the alternative correct?

> I'll go with the candidate to whom I am used.

It seems to me that the meaning of the phrase 'used to' is tied explicitly to the word order and actually doesn't have meaning apart from its tradition, and breaking it up would destroy the faux meaning. I can't think of any other cases where the verb 'use' takes the proposition 'to.'

Is that correct? If not, is there another way to do it without ending a sentence in a preposition?

Comment: I'm talking about 'used to' in the sense of familiarity. I am used to having dinner at 6. Alternatively, I am in the habit of, it is my practice to, I have experience with.

Comment: @Rathony What makes me think that 'used to' is tied to word order is that in the second example, when the word order is changed, it doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @Rathony thanks, I'll let someone who knows English answer this question.

Comment: @Rathony woo. Capital letter. Happy? Now, which relative pronoun are you talking about?

Comment: @Rathony I'm going to assume you're talking about 'which candidate.' Corrected that.

Comment: "Used to" is idiomatic and to split it up for sake of not ending with a preposition would make it sound odd, as you suspected.  If the ending-in-a-preposition thing bothers you, then it is probably preferable to use "accustomed" or "familiar" instead.  FWIW, ending in a preposition is not a penalty-of-death sin. :-)

Comment: Both are correct. Which you choose is up to you (opinion-based).

Answer (score 4):

There is *absolutely positively completely* nothing wrong grammatically with ending a sentence with a preposition. This was a bogus rule made up by grammarians to sell grammar books, and ignores the way Germanic languages work. Some people cling to the rule, but it is a question of style, not grammar.

Furthermore, *used to* has become, in practice, a lexical element, which is not easily split: "to whom I am used" is awkward and may be misunderstood.

Thirdly, "go with" (in this sense) is a colloquial expression, and does not match the formal nature of "to whom".

> I'll go with the candidate I'm used to.

every time.

Comment: _"to whom I am used"_--not to mention the pronunciation of "used" if such a sentence were to read aloud.